# Sitecore - Standard roles for users

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

I'm creating users for a practice project and came up with three  - *author*, *reviewer*, *publisher*.

*author* - should be able to create, edit and delete items.
*reviewer* - should only be able to read and approve items.
*publisher* - should only be able to read all items and publish those that have been approved.

I read in an article that these roles would suffice for a content author - **Sitecore Client Authoring** & **Sitecore Client Users**, and so assigned the same to *author*.

When logged in as *author*, the insert option is greyed out !!!!. So, I logged in as admin again and tried giving access to the Home item (read, write etc) for *author*, but it says access denied.

Please clarify for me the following:
1. The users I thought of, are they correct or work good in a real scenario?
2. Why am I not able to give access for *author* to the Home item.
3. Is creating a custom role necessary. Should there not be a sitecore standard role(s) already for these users which are common for every project.
4. Kindly suggest the roles that I should assign for my *author*, *reviewer* and *publisher*

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't really fit the guidelines for SO,  but to answer your questions:

1. It's uncommon to have a dedicated publisher.  More common is to have workflow that automatically publishes once content is approved i would expect. You can likely get away with just 2 roles.
2. Those roles should be enough but check the doco,  please clarify whether your admin user is getting the 'access denied'  message or your author.  Admin users should not be denied anything; likely your security setup is causing the problem (item permissions,  not roles)
3. Standard roles are granular to allow you to tune your setup.  There are a number of sample sites you can get (like launchsitecore.net) that can show you how to use these roles,  plus there's documentation.  You can also post to community.sitecore.net
4. There's a combination of roles and privileges required to achieve this too detailed for SO.  Refer to documentation,  various blogs,  or a sample site to see how to use the security features in a real world application.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it using the Workflow feature and altering security rights on the workflow level. The simplest workflow structure should be like:

Initial step 1

- Submit command (moves item to step 2)

Awaiting Approval step 2

- Approve command (moves item to step 3)
- Reject command (moves item to
  step 1)

Awaiting Publishing step 3

- Publish command (moves item to step 4)
- Reject command (moves items to
  step 2)

Published final step 4

- Auto Publish action (standard action that will publish item automatically as soon as item appears in the final state)

All 3 roles should be a member of at least `Sitecore\Author` role. It allows basic access to item editing features. Do not forget to explicitly allow Write etc access using the `Security Editor` application. If it doesn’t work for some reason check current rights using the `Access Viewer` application, once you select some particular security account and item, you should be able to inspect allowed and denied rights with explanation on the right side.

Then you need to set access on the workflow level (for instance, a reviewer can execute the Approve and Reject commands in the “Awaiting Approval” state, and can’t  - in other states. Same for author and publisher).

Useful docs (valid for Sitecore 8.x as well):
https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Security%20Reference.aspx
https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Workflow%20Reference.aspx

Comment: "All 3 roles should be a member of at least Sitecore\Author role. It allows basic access to item editing features." But the reviewer & publisher should not be able to edit items. Isn't it the way it should be in real time. Please clarify